# Addressbook app and supporting existing formats

Tags: email, outlook, contacts

I need to implement an address book feature into an inventory app that I'm making, and I know that my client is always switching between different addressbook apps and email clients, and she always imports and exports info between them.

SO, I was thinking why not let her export contacts from within my app to an Outlook contact file or something.

But is this OK to do? Are we allowed to do it? And where abouts should I go for more information about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can generate [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard)s if Outlook will import that format?

Edit: Also, if you are using Visual Studio (C# or VB.NET) try looking into [the interop libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx). For example, in VS 2008, File > New Project, under Visual C# > Office, pick Outlook 2007 Add-in. See [all questions on StackOverflow about office-interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-interop).

Comment: Yeah, I remember those. I think Outlook does support them. I'll check out that link. Thanks!